# Deprecated commonfy function in booru discord.js

Tags: discord.js

[image]

This is an NSFW command and whenever I run it spits out this error. Here's my code:

```js
const booru = require('booru');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "nsfw",
    description: "Sends a random R18+ image.",
    async execute(message, args) {
        if (!message.channel.nsfw) return message.channel.send("Sorry, but you have to do this command in a NSFW channel.");
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please provide a search query.");

        const search = args[0];

        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("loli" || "shota" || "gore")) return message.channel.send("Sorry, but i'm not allowed to search for that type of stuff");
        
        var query = args[0];
        booru.search('rule34', [query], {nsfw: true, limit: 1, random: true })
            .then(booru.commonfy)
            .then(images => {
                for (let image of images) {
                    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setImage(image.common.file_url)
                    .setColor('#FF0000')
                    .setFooter(`Tags: ${query}`)
                    .setURL(image.common.file_url);
                return message.channel.send({ embed });
                }
            }).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
    },
};
```

I think it has to do something at 17:25, the: .then(booru.commonfy) part.

Here's the Documentation for booru: https://www.npmjs.com/package/booru, and here's the code I forked: https://github.com/Aaronidk/Dorito-bot-discord.js/blob/master/commands/NSFW/r34.js

Comment: Looks like this is an error with your package.

Comment: What does `booru.commonfy` do? Could not find it in the docs.

Comment: @hexerous, here it is https://booru.js.org/modules/index.html#deprecatedcommonfy

Comment: It says, 'Common is now deprecated, just access the properties directly', is there a problem with doing this?

Comment: Also, this is just a warning, not an error. Your code works perfectly fine with this warning (until the function gets removed). If you still don't like it showing up every time you can just do what the docs say.